# Decoding JSON array with unicode character

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I have the following JSON array:

```
[u'steve@gmail.com']
```

"u" is apparently the unicode character, and it was automatically created by Python. Now, I want to bring this back into Objective-C and decode it into an array using this:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)arrayFromJSON:(NSString*)json
{
    if(!json) return nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   //I've also tried NSUnicodeStringEncoding here, same thing
    NSError *e;
    NSMutableArray *result= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
    if (e != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@", e.description);
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, I get an error: `(Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 1.)`

How do I remedy this?

Edit: Here's how I bring the entity from Python back into objective-c:

First I convert the entity to a dictionary:

```
def to_dict(self):
    return dict((p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()
                if getattr(self, p) is not None)
```

I add this dictionary to a list, set the value of my responseDict['entityList'] to this list, then `self.response.out.write(json.dumps(responseDict))`

However the result I get back still has that 'u' character.

Comment: I think you should fix your Python code to print out Unicode, since that JSON is not valid.

Comment: Have you used the python `json` library to serialize the content to json?

Comment: Try using `str()` in place of `unicode()` in the above.  What type of object is returned by `getattr(self, p)`?  Does that object override __str__ or __repr__?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[u'steve@gmail.com'] is the decoded python value of the array it is not valid JSON.

The valid JSON string data would be just `["steve@gmail.com"]`.

Dump the data from python back into a JSON string by doing:

```
import json
python_data = [u'steve@gmail.com']
json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

The `u` prefix on python string literals indicates that those strings are unicode rather than the default encoding in python2.X (ASCII).

Comment: Well I'm using Google App Engine, and storing values into a StringListProperty. I store each string one by one, and they are stored for some reason with a 'u' in the beginning. How can I stop it from storing that 'u' in the first place?

Comment: It's not storing the u character, that's a cosmetic prefix that indicates the string is unicode encoded.  Please update your question with how you're returning the data in Python to your Objective-C code.  You need to encode the StringListProperty value to JSON using `json.dumps / json.dump`.